# show node when editing a comment

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When editing a comment, the comment is shown alone, without its associated node. I found no solution to show the comment editing form together with the node on the same page. When creating a new comment, I can configure Drupal to show both on the same page. I thought about
modifying the comment form by a template file and include the node into this template file, but I think, this is an ugly and difficult solution.

thanks in advance for any hints, Gregor Hyneck

Answer (score 2):

You cannot configure it as such. But if you are willing to create a module, the code needed is simple:

```
showcomment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "comment_form") { #you might want to make this test smarter, to avoid admin-interface and general comment-form from changing.
    $form['node_preview'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('node', $form['#node']),
    );
  }  
}
```

Obviously, your production code will need a few extra tests to avoid the node from rendering on each comment-form. And you probably don't want the generic theme_node, but a custom one, rendering only the essentials of the node (title+teaser or so).

Comment: Thank you very much @berkes, nice! I already had an module but not too much experience with theming. I only had to alter theme('node', $form['#node']) into drupal_render(node_view($form['#node'], 'full'))